# Exposing warnings from data objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm exposing Data objects via service oriented assembly (which on future usages might become a WCF service).

The data object is tree designed, as well as formed from allot of properties.
I now want to expose data flow warnings and wondering what's the best way to do it having to things to consider: (1) seperation (2) ease of access. On the one hand, i want the UI team to be able to access a fields warnings (or errors) without having them mapping the field names to an external source but on the other hand, i don't want the warnings "hanged" on the object itself (as i don't see it a correct design).

I tought of creating a new type of wrapper for each field, that'll expose events and they'll have to register the one's they care about (but totally not sure)
I'll be happy to hear your thoughts.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's best to show your proposed design and ask specific questions about it. You've mentioned a few options here, all of which are still very abstract.

Comment: Have you considered existing things like IDataErrorInfo ?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks, IDataErrorInfo doesn't address the separation issue i mentioned, as it keeps both the data and the errors on the same class. Anything else ?

Comment: Maybe you could return a type that has the return value in one property and an error collection in another?

Comment: What do you mean by "expose data flow warnings"? Why do you want to expose them? Is it a business requirement?

Comment: Are you separating commands from queries? Commands can return an error message, but you should query for data without modifying it.

Comment: Ryan hi: It still means that i have to couple the errors and the object's data. Using the command pattern is not possible since i'm not putting any execution (BL) methods on the data object. 
Olivehour: yea it is. for example: the object was loaded with only 3 out of the 4 properties because he didn't have sufficient permissions to load the forth one. a warning would be: "4th object was not loaded due to insufficient permissions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDataErrorInfo` (re: comments on the question) is an interface. You can *do* whatever the heck you want. Said another way, it's a concept that does sound like it's a good place to start.

`IDataErrorInfo`'s properties could simply be accessors to a dictionary-like structure/object that contains field:errorMessage pairs. The dictionary has the field name as a string - no references to real Data objects at all.

I can see `DataError` objects, if you will, mirroring the Data object hierarchical structure with `IDataErrorInfo` implemented at each level. Given this common interface you can recursively drill down getting error message sets for any arbitrary level of the Data.